# How to update the blue dot marker for current location in MapView in Android

Tags: android, android-mapview, mapbox-marker

I have a fragment which when normally launched shows a mapview with current user location shown as blue dot marker. I have a feature to launch this screen from another place and can pass latitude and longitude values. Based on these values, I update the latitude and longitude of "MapboxMap". The location is updated on map and camera zooms to it but blue dot marker still shows as user current location. How can I update the blue dot marker to be shown as new location given by latitude and longitude value:

My code to update location:

```
private void goToUserLocation() {

        double requestedLatitude = 0;
        double requestedLongitude = 0;

        if (mapboxMap == null || !getUserVisibleHint()) {
            return;
        }
        if (!DeviceUtil.isLocationServiceEnabled(getContext().getApplicationContext())) {
            showLocationDisabledSnackbar();
            return;
        }
        enableUserLocationMarker();
        Location location = mapboxMap.getMyLocation();
        //Get the requested coordinates if it exists
        if(location != null) {
            try {
                Uri intentData = getActivity().getIntent().getData();
                if (null != intentData) {
                    String latitude = intentData.getQueryParameter("lat");
                    String longitude = intentData.getQueryParameter("lon");

                    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(latitude) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(longitude)) {

                            requestedLatitude = Double.parseDouble(latitude);
                            requestedLongitude = Double.parseDouble(longitude);

                            if ((requestedLatitude >= -90 && requestedLatitude <= 90) &&
                                    (requestedLongitude >= -90d && requestedLongitude <= 90d)) {
                                location.setLatitude(requestedLatitude);
                                location.setLongitude(requestedLongitude);
                            }
                    }

                }
            }catch (NumberFormatException ex) {

            }
            finally {
                goToLocation(location);
            }
        }
        fetchNearbyPages();
    }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Hi hope this will help.

First, override the onLocatioChanged method and pass the updated location to separate created setCameraToCurrentPosition method. ex. is as follows:-

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    setCameraToCurrentPosition(Location location);
}

private void setCameraToCurrentPosition(Location location) {
    setCameraPosition(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()), 16, 6500);

    // Here you need to add the marker to current position of user on map.

}
```